# Conditional container declaration in k8s config

Tags: kubernetes

I am using v1beta2 of kubernetes and I have `Deployment` kind of configuration. 
In this configuration, I have a base conf of my app and I want to add **conditionally** a second docker image (container) in the same pod.

My config file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${MY_APP_NAME}
spec:
   containers:
    - name: my_first_container
      image: image_url
[...]
    - name: my_second_container <------ I want to put conditional declaration of this container
[...]
```

I don't want to add the second container in a spearate pod.

The condition is based on a variable like ${K8S_CONTAINER2_CONDITION} valued by sed command in linux. 
This command replace variables like ${MY_APP_NAME}.

How can I put conditional declaration of this container ? 
For some applications, I need to deploy both containers and for others, only the first one. But I have only one k8s configuration file (yaml).

Comment: No solution yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look at helm charts for customizing the deployment file at deploy time